# Multiple subquery

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I have 3 tables: Table1, Table2, Table3

I want to make a query that use Table1's result as Table2's constrain, Table2's result as Table3's constrain

so my query now is something like:

```
SELECT tb3.id 
FROM tb3 
WHERE tb3.tag = (
                   SELECT tb2.num 
                   FROM tb2 
                   WHERE tb2.name = (
                                      SELECT tb1.user 
                                      FROM tb1 
                                      WHERE check = '0'
                                    )
                 )
```

for example,

tb1 has item 'tb1.check', 'tb1.user';

tb2 has item 'tb2.num', 'tb2.name';

tb3 has item 'tb3.tag', 'tb3.id';

first check tb1 for data where 'tb1.check'= 0 , then get its 'tb1.user',

then check tb2 for data where 'tb2.name' = 'tb1.user' and get 'tb2.num',

and so, check tb3 for data where 'tb3.tag' = 'tb2.num' then get 'tb3.id'

but all I get is empty, any help?

Comment: "but I can't get what I want" Do you get an error? Wrong results? Can you show some example data and show what you want, and what you get?

Comment: An empty result is a perfectly valid result for that query. Whether it returns rows depends on what data you have. Can you show your table structure and some example data and explain what result you expect for that data?

Comment: for example, tb1 has item 'tb1.check', 'tb1.user'; tb2 has item 'tb2.num', 'tb2.name';  tb3 has item 'tb3.tag', 'tb3.id'; I'll check tb1 for data which 'tb1.check'= 0 , then get its 'tb1.user', then check db2 for data where 'tb2.name' = 'tb1.user' and get 'tb2.num', and so, check for data in db3 where 'tb3.tag' = 'tb2.num' then get its 'id'

Comment: I finally got this solved, the reason why I can't get any data is the item's collation between tb3 and tb2 is different - utf8_general and utf8_unicode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `INNER JOIN` instead of subquery as:

```
SELECT tb3.id 
FROM tb3 
     INNER JOIN tb2  
         ON tb3.tag = tb2.num
     INNER JOIN Invitation inv
         ON tb2.name = inv.user AND
            inv.check = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can do that using `JOIN`

```
SELECT tb3.id 
FROM   tb3 
        INNER JOIN tb2  
            ON tb3.tag = tb2.num
        INNER JOIN Invitation inv
            ON tb2.name = inv.user
WHERE   inv.check = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
SELECT tb3.id 
FROM tb3,tab2,tab1 
WHERE tb3.tag = tb2.num and 
tb2.name = tb1.user and 
tb1.check = '0'
```

Comment: Yes, although it's more correct to use `JOIN`s to differentiate real `WHERE` filters from `WHERE` joins.